# How to install custom mainline kernel in Ubuntu snappy core?

Tags: kernel, ubuntu, snappy

I have cloned latest Torvalds kernel, compiled it for the Raspberry Pi 2 model B and generated deb packages as well. When I install them using `dpkg -i *.deb` the files under `/boot/firmware` are not updated.

Could you please support me to properly install the mainline kernel on a Raspberry Pi 2 model B?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi SE.  Be sure to take the tour to see how this works and to earn a badge:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/Tour

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is because you are using the stock kernel. There is an official kernel building guide at the [Raspberry Pi Foundation website](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md) that works well for compiling on your Pi, or on your (Linux) desktop for your Pi.

So as long as you follow that guide you should not have any problems.

Comment: Additionally the package rpikernelhack. is used for packaged updates of kernel and is necessary due to the file system of the boot partition and the details of dpkg  . This question has a lot of great info https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/51410/71180