# How to Package Custom RPI Kernel into *.deb?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, kernel

I have compiled a custom Raspbian kernel from source because i need to enable the CONFIG_AUDIT flags for installing SELinux & Auditd.

Following the [Official Kernel Documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md) i was able to do this and it works well.

I now need to package this into a `*.deb` so i am able to install it on other Pi's with without having to manually copy the `*.dtb` and `*.img` and run `sudo make modules_install` on every pi i want to deploy this to.

---

This is where i run into problems

I have done some investigations and found a few ways to do this on Standard Debian following [this Guide](https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/custom-kernels-distros/custom-compiled-kernel-debian-ubuntu/) and using the recommended `make deb-pkg` although when i run `dpkg -i linux-*.deb` on a fresh Pi and reboot it bricks it.

I have also tried to create my own `*.deb` file. By copying the `zImage modules dtbs` into the custom `dpkg-deb` along with redirecting the modules install path to that package too with `make INSTALL_MOD_PATH=$INSTALLDIR modules_install` and running `dpkg-deb --build [custom-dir]`. This also failed

i have not been able to find out how to create a rpikernelhack pkg either as seen [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51410/what-is-rpikernelhack)

---

Any help in packaging a custom kernel for the Raspberry Pi 3b+ would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello. Have you tried comparing your efforts with the official Raspberry Pi kernel packages to see if there's an oddity you're missing? Might shed some light on the matter.

Comment: Probably simpler to just write a simple install script and pack it in a tarball with the required files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a bash script capable to do this: **`create-debian-rpi-package.sh`**

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
#
#   @Ephemeral
#
#   USAGE:
#
#   sudo bash create-debian-rpi-package.sh create PACKAGENAME
#   sudo dpkg -i PACKAGENAME.deb
#   sudo bash create-debian-rpi-package.sh clean PACKAGENAME
#
# sudo tail -f /var/log/dpkg.log


ARCHITECTURE="armhf" # RPi3B, test: raspbian buster

PROJECT=/tmp


function CREATE(){
if [ ! -d "${PROJECT}/package/DEBIAN" ];then
    mkdir -p "${PROJECT}/package/DEBIAN"
else
    echo "A temporary directory ${PROJECT}/package already exists !"
    echo "You can use 'sudo bash create-debian-rpi-package.sh clean'"
    exit 0
fi;
cd "${PROJECT}/package"




echo "creating embeded files..."
#mkdir -p ./boot/overlays
#cp arch/arm/boot/dts/*dtb ./boot
#cp arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/*.dtb* ./boot/overlays/
#cp arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/README ./boot/overlays/
#cp arch/arm/boot/zImage ./boot/$KERNEL.img
mkdir -p ./usr/bin/
echo "ip a" > ./usr/bin/mytool.sh


cd "DEBIAN"


echo "creating pre install file, use this for saving KERNEL..."
cat << EOF > preinst
#!/bin/sh
echo "pre install job"
BACKUP_DIR="/home/pi/boot-backup-\$(date +%m-%d-%Y_%H-%M-%S)"
echo "Creating /boot backup in \${BACKUP_DIR}"
if [ ! -d "\${BACKUP_DIR}" ];then
    mkdir "\${BACKUP_DIR}"
    cp -R /boot "\${BACKUP_DIR}"
fi;
exit 0
EOF
chmod 0755 preinst



echo "creating control file..."
cat << EOF > control
Package: ${PACKAGENAME}
Version: 0.1-0
Architecture: ${ARCHITECTURE}
Maintainer: ${PACKAGENAME} <${PACKAGENAME}@debian.org>
Description: utility package
EOF


echo "creating post install file..."
cat << EOF > postinst
#!/bin/sh
echo "post install job"
#chmod -R +x /boot/overlays
#chmod +x /boot/$KERNEL.img
#chmod +x /boot/*.dtb
exit 0
EOF
chmod 0755 postinst


echo "building debian package ${PACKAGENAME}.deb ..."
cd ..
dpkg-deb --build /tmp/package
if [ ${?} -eq "0" ];then
    mv /tmp/package.deb /tmp/${PACKAGENAME}.deb
    echo "SUCCESS building /tmp/${PACKAGENAME}.deb"
    echo -e "\nINSTALL\nsudo dpkg -i /tmp/${PACKAGENAME}.deb\n\n"
fi
}

function CLEAN(){
    rm -R /tmp/package
    rm -R /tmp/${PACKAGENAME}.deb
    dpkg --purge ${PACKAGENAME}
}



if [ -z "${SUDO_USER}" ];then
    echo "Sorry you must an sudo user for running this script."
    exit 0
fi
case ${1} in
    create|CREATE|Create)if [ -z "${2}" ];then echo "You must provide the package name."; exit 0; else PACKAGENAME="${2}";fi; CREATE;;
    clean|CLEAN|Clean)if [ -z "${2}" ];then echo "You must provide the package name."; exit 0;else PACKAGENAME="${2}";fi; CLEAN;;
    *)echo -e "Unknown option ${1}\nOptions are: CREATE or CLEAN";;
esac
```

The output of the script when I create a package named `mypackage`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo bash create-debian-rpi-package.sh create mypackage
creating embeded files...
creating pre install file, use this for saving KERNEL...
creating control file...
creating post install file...
building debian package mypackage.deb ...
dpkg-deb: building package 'mypackage' in '/tmp/package.deb'.
SUCCESS building /tmp/mypackage.deb

INSTALL
sudo dpkg -i /tmp/mypackage.deb


pi@raspberrypi:~$ sudo dpkg -i /tmp/mypackage.deb
Selection of the previously unselected mypackage package.
(Reading the database... 152119 files and directories already installed.)
Preparing unpacking of /tmp/mypackage.deb ...
pre install job
Creating /boot backup in /home/pi/boot-backup-07-10-2019_18-17-05
Unpacking mypackage (0.1-0) ...
Parameterization of mypackage (0.1-0) ...
post install job

pi@raspberrypi:~$sudo bash create-debian-rpi-package.sh clean mypackage
(Reading the database ... 152120 files and directories already installed.)
Deleting mypackage (0.1-0) ...
```

But, because it's relativly dangerous to copy file into /boot directory, I have not uncommented the code for your case precisly (all `cp arm/...`) . I have put an example with `/usr/bin` directory and a `bash script` installation.
I have added a pre-install function, this function create a backup directory in `/home/pi/boot-backup-$(date)` of the `/boot` directory before installing any files.

For your case you must :

- uncomment the line where you copy your new kernel, adjust full `arm/` path and  adjust `$KERNEL.img` name.
- uncomment the `chmod +x` because all file in /boot seems to are executable in the post install file creation (yes after the copy of your files, they must exist so that we can apply them the rights).

### Additionally

As specified [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md), you can add, once the installation is done and thus in the **posinst file**, a line with sed for example to replace `kernel=kernel-myconfig.img` in `/boot/config.txt` with the name of your kernel img and then ask the user if he wants to restart or not with his new kernel for example ...

Comment: Thank-you this was exactly what i needed and worked a treat. a few small modifications, some of the move directories were hard set to `/tmp/` an easy fix to `{$PROJECT}`, and i also added the kernel modules to the script too i was able to do this by `make INSTALL_MOD_PATH=$INSTALLDIR modules_install` and copying the contents into the `*.deb`

but a very handy little script Cheers.